# MySql JSON data type not using the correct encoding

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to store json data into a column with JSON data type in MySql.

Here is the table:

```
    CREATE DATABASE `testutf8` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
USE testutf8;
CREATE TABLE t2(jdoc JSON, sdoc TEXT);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES('{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "å": "value3"}','{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "å": "value3"}');
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

However I get this result:

```
jdoc:
{"Ã¥": "value3", "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}    
sdoc:
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "å": "value3"}
```

Apparently the column with JSON data type doesn't encode the characters correctly.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How are you storing and retrieving the JSON? Maybe the encoding is wrong at another layer.

Comment: @shmosel: The codes above is how I stored and retrieve the JSON. So there is no another layer.

Comment: You can't run queries without some sort of client.

Comment: @shmosel: I'm running it in IntelliJ.

Comment: @shmosel: Yes it's the client's fault.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ has encoding issue for JSON data type.